# How to modify only select parameters/attributes of an XML file with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Say, if I have an arbitrary XML file, is there any way to modify only a certain parameter/attribute without changing the rest of the XML file? For instance, let's take this simple example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- The xml file itself contains many other tags -->
  <ConfigSection>
    <GeneralParams>
      <parameter key="TableName" value="MyTable1" />
    </GeneralParams>
  </ConfigSection>
</configuration>
```

How can I update the value for the key `TableName` to "MyTable2"?

Comment: Did you consider a Google for this question? It gets asked at once per week and is trivial to figure out with the `XmlDocument` and `XDocument` libraries Microsoft provides. With 1,300+ rep, you should know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way, but give a try.

```
string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <configuration>
          <!-- The xml file itself contains many other tags -->
          <ConfigSection>
            <GeneralParams>
              <parameter key=""TableName"" value=""MyTable1"" />
            </GeneralParams>
          </ConfigSection>
        </configuration>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xdoc.Descendants("parameter")
    .Single(x => x.Attribute("key").Value == "TableName" && x.Attribute("value").Value == "MyTable1")
    .Attributes("value").First().Value = "MyTable2";
```

Comment: Thank you, my friend. Do I need to save the xml doc at some point, though?

Comment: Use `xdoc.Save` method, or `xdoc.ToString` to convert as string

Answer (score 1):

There is another way using XmlDocument.

```
            string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
                            <configuration>
                              <ConfigSection>
                                <GeneralParams>
                                  <parameter key='TableName' value='MyTable1' />
                                </GeneralParams>
                              </ConfigSection>
                            </configuration>";

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

            XmlNode paramter;
            XmlNode root = xDoc.DocumentElement;

            paramter = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("//parameter/@key");
            paramter.LastChild.InnerText = "MyTable2";

            string modifiedxml = xDoc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: For new implementations. `XDocument` should be preferred. The programming model is nicer and it needs no horrible casting when extracting elements.